# How to remove or edit work item types

Tags: youtrack

At the **time tracking** tab, there is a `Add work item type to the project...` button. How to remove, or at least, edit added work item types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward to me as there's remove button on the same tab:

[image]

Comment: It removes a work type from the project, not from  the drop down list.

Comment: I see. To remove it completely navigate to global time tracking settings under the nut icon and remove work item type from there. Low level admin permission is required for that.

Comment: Thanks! I missed Time Tracking menu from the settings dropdown. There are some another settings that I was looking for.